# How to add a rectangle in Visio from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-visio

I am trying to modify a page in Visio from Excel

I tried this code but without success:

```
Sub DrawMyRectangles()
    Dim draw_visio As Object
    Set draw_visio = CreateObject("visio.application")
    Dim rect1 As Visio.Shape

    Set rect1 = draw_visio.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
    rect1.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Please look more info about method [DrawRectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/shape-drawrectangle-method-Visio)

```
Set rect1 = draw_visio.ActiveWindow.Page.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
```